# No login prompt in QEMU serial console

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu

I'm running an [Ubuntu Jammy Desktop](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/) VM in QEMU. The host system is also Ubuntu Jammy. The command is:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -nodefaults \
  -machine q35,accel=kvm \
  -cpu host \
  -smp 2 \
  -m 2G \
  -chardev vc,id=monitor \
  -mon monitor \
  -serial vc \
  -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd \
  -cdrom jammy-desktop-amd64.iso
```

When I go to the serial console with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`2`, I can see a GRUB menu there (as expected). Then I hit enter to start the system. From this point on the console remains silent, and **there is no login prompt**.

I am confused because I used to do exactly the same thing on a Mac (M2) as a host machine, and I always got a login prompt, like here:

[image]

Why doesn't this work on Linux/AMD64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because nothing told Linux to start a login console there. That is not the default; it's something Ubuntu does specifically for their bootable ISOs on ARM.

It seems that Ubuntu pre-configure their ARM images to redirect both the bootloader and the Linux console to an available serial port, because often that's the only output that an ARM-based system has. (It is *far* more common for users to boot ARM distributions on something like a Raspberry Pi than on a MacBook.)

x86 devices, on the other hand, do not usually have that issue – they always have a firmware-provided text console output available – and that's what both GRUB and Linux use as their default console. Redirecting to a serial port (which is increasingly rare on x86<sup>1,2</sup>) has never been the default at any time; such configuration is usually left to the user on most distributions.

(In addition, only one device can really be set as the target for /dev/console, so if it is redirected to serial, you wouldn't have system boot messages on the firmware VGA console (unless the distribution used e.g. Plymouth which can duplicate the messages) – it'd be silent until the login prompt shows up.)

If you have access to the bootloader screen, edit the kernel command line to specify `console=ttyS0,115200` to redirect /dev/console; this will make boot output go to the first serial port (COM1). Systemd will then also automatically start a `serial-getty@ttyS0` service to provide a login prompt as well.

If you don't have access to the bootloader screen, you'll have to modify the ISO image to edit the bootloader configuration (GRUB or more likely Syslinux/isolinux). By doing this you can also add the necessary options to redirect the bootloader itself over serial as well.

With recent systemd versions there is a mechanism to pass additional boot options via DMI data (which Qemu has an option for) but I haven't investigated that yet. It would help you start a serial-getty service, though not see the rest of the boot process (the mechanism is handled by init, not by the kernel).

---

<sup>1</sup> (Or set to a very slow rate, or redirected to a network, etc. Trying to output data to a nonexistent serial port can sometimes cause problems.)

<sup>2</sup> (Rarity aside, it's also common for x86 systems to have non-terminal devices attached to ttyS0, and I've seen quite a few people complain about ModemManager sending probe 'AT' commands to their GPS receiver or whatever; similarly Windows famously used to probe all serial ports for mice on every startup, which Linux users also like to make fun out of. So I suspect that sending out "ubuntu login:" by default wouldn't be well-received.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but sparks more questions, though: Is "firmware-provided text console output" something non-graphical that I can configure in QEMU to get my login prompt? Where can I see Ubuntu configs for each platform, e.g. the one that enables serial port for ARM64?

Comment: It's the BIOS console or UEFI console – it's displayed on the same graphical `-vga` output that the graphical login prompt eventually takes over. You can get a text login prompt there by preventing startup of the graphical login (booting with `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` in the kernel command line), or by using the Linux "virtual terminal switch" keys (sending Ctrl-Alt-F2..F6 to the VM keyboard)

Comment: OK, so as far as I can understand you, I must either change the kernel command line to output on serial, or add a VGA device to my QEMU. For the purpose I'm doing it for, I should be OK with adding `console=ttyS0,115200`. I can accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: You might find https://systemd.io/CREDENTIALS/ useful – at the very least I think it provides a way to pass the systemd-specific kernel options (e.g. `systemd.wants=serial-getty@ttyS0.service`) through Qemu, but I only faintly remember that and haven't looked into it much further.